# Agregar animación a carrusel para desplazarse de derecha a izquierda y viceversa

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día amigos desarrolladores.

Tengo un carrusel parecido a los de `bootstrap` que contiene 4 items y por medio de `JavaScript` detecto que al dar click en la flecha siguiente o atrás me oculte el ultimo o primer ítem y solo me deje visible en este caso los 3 restantes.

Generaría el siguiente efecto: [1,2,3]… [2,3,4]… [3,4,5]…[4,5,6]… Esto lo logro alternando de posición los `div` internos del carrusel y utilizando las propiedades `display: block` y `none`. También es posible que por el valor de una variable puedo elegir cuantos `div` voy a visualizar.

Hasta el momento todo funciona de maravilla, lo que quiero y aun me falta es añadirle una transición para que deslice los `div` de derecha a izquierda y viceversa.

Codigo Html:

```js
Mi_Carrucel_Datia("mi_carrucel", 3, "boton1", "boton2");
Mi_Carrucel_Datia("mi_carrucel_2", 5, "boton3", "boton4");

function Mi_Carrucel_Datia($var_Carrucel, $var_Visibles, $btn_Atras, $btn_Siguiente) {
  console.log("Objeto: " + $var_Carrucel + " - Cantidad: " + $var_Visibles + " - Boton atras: " + $btn_Atras + " - Boton derecha: " + $btn_Siguiente);
  $ind_Int = 0;
  $var_Visibles--;
  $var_Movimiento = 100 / $var_Visibles;
  //ocular otros
  $('#' + $var_Carrucel + '>div').each(function() {

    console.log("Div: " + $(this).index());
    if ($(this).index() > $var_Visibles) {
      $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
  });

  $btn_izq = document.getElementById($btn_Siguiente);
  $btn_izq.addEventListener('click', function() {

    console.log("Atras: " + $(this).prop("id") + " - Objeto: " + $var_Carrucel);
    $var_item_Temp = $('#' + $var_Carrucel).children('div :first');
    $('#' + $var_Carrucel).append($var_item_Temp);
    //$('#' + $var_Carrucel).children('div :first').remove();
    $('#' + $var_Carrucel + '>div').each(function() {

      console.log("Div: " + $(this).index());
      if ($(this).index() > $var_Visibles) {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
      } else {
        $(this).css("display", "block");
      }
    });

  }, false);

  $btn_der = document.getElementById($btn_Atras);
  $btn_der.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("Siguiente: " + $(this).prop("id") + " - Objeto: " + $var_Carrucel);
    $var_item_Temp = $('#' + $var_Carrucel).children('div :last');
    $('#' + $var_Carrucel).prepend($var_item_Temp);

    $('#' + $var_Carrucel + '>div').each(function() {

      console.log("Div: " + $(this).index());
      if ($(this).index() > $var_Visibles) {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
      } else {
        $(this).css("display", "block");
      }
    });

  }, false);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 80px;border: 1px solid; height: 200px;">
  Mi carrucel primero

  <div id="mi_carrucel" class="row">
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 1
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 4
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
numero 5
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
numero 6
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
numero 7
</div> -->
  </div>
  <div id="boton1">
    Atras
  </div>
  <div id="boton2">
    Siguiente
  </div>

</div>
<div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 80px;border: 1px solid; height: 200px;">
  Mi carrucel segundo

  <div id="mi_carrucel_2" class="row">
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 1
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 2
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 3
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 4
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 5
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 6
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid;">
      numero 7
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="boton3">
    Atras
  </div>
  <div id="boton4">
    Siguiente
  </div>


</div>
```